# jQuery select by attribute using AND and OR operators

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, find, operators

I'm thinking about, if it is possible in jQuery to select elements by named attributes using AND and OR.

Example:

```
<div myid="1" myc="blue">1</div>
<div myid="2" myc="blue">2</div>
<div myid="3" myc="blue">3</div>
<div myid="4">4</div>
```

I'd like to select all the elements where `myc="blue"` but only those with `myid` set to either 1 or 3.

So I tried:

```
a=$('[myc="blue"] [myid="1"]  [myid="3"]');
```

but it does not work, same here:

```
a=$('[myc="blue"] && [myid="1"] || [myid="3"]');
```

Is it possible without writing special filter functions?

Comment: NB: You shouldn't be making up your own attributes like `myc` and `myid`. If you are using HTML5 prefix them with `data-`: `data-myc` and `data-myid`.

Comment: @RoToRa, is there documentation in HTML5 that says you should do such? Most websites I see use whatever the developer's brain thinks about at the time...

Comment: Just because people do it, it doesn't mean it's correct. See [HTML5 Section 3.2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#semantics-0): "Authors must not use elements, attributes, or attribute values that are not permitted by this specification or other applicable specifications, as doing so makes it significantly harder for the language to be extended in the future."

Comment: It's a poor example of a good question. What about different element types like inputs?

Answer (score 234, accepted):

**AND** operation

```
a=$('[myc="blue"][myid="1"][myid="3"]');
```

**OR** operation, use commas

```
a=$('[myc="blue"],[myid="1"],[myid="3"]');
```

As @Vega commented:

```
a=$('[myc="blue"][myid="1"],[myc="blue"][myid="3"]');
```

Comment: I think, he want's the `myc == blue && (id == 1 || id == 3)`

Comment: if i use `a=$('[myc="blue"] [myid="1"],[myid="3"]');`does it mean `([myc="blue"] AND [myid="1"]) OR [myid="3"]` or `([myc="blue"]) AND ([myid="1"] OR [myid="3"])`  I'm looking for the 2nd one //Edit: thank you for that update! :-)

Answer (score 19):

Simple use [`.filter()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) (AND) using the [*multiple selector* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) (OR):

```
$('[myc="blue"]').filter('[myid="1"],[myid="2"]');
```

In general, chaining selectors, like `a.foo.bar[attr=value]` is some kind of AND selector.

jQuery has [extensive documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) about the supported selectors, it's worth a read.

Comment: do you know, if this is faster than the answer from gabe?

Comment: I don't know, maybe, maybe not.

Comment: This is more maintainable, so faster to read and debug (which tends to be the most expensive resource).

Answer (score 12):

How about writing a filter like below,

```
$('[myc="blue"]').filter(function () {
   return (this.id == '1' || this.id == '3');
});
```

**Edit:** @Jack Thanks.. totally missed it..

```
$('[myc="blue"]').filter(function() {
   var myId = $(this).attr('myid');   
   return (myId == '1' || myId == '3');
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/j8kpB/)

Answer (score 8):

The and operator in a selector is just an empty string, and the or operator is the comma.

There is however no grouping or priority, so you have to repeat one of the conditions:

```
a=$('[myc=blue][myid="1"],[myc=blue][myid="3"]');
```

Comment: do you need those quotes? I mean just for consistency.. probably just me. >.<

Comment: @Vega: You don't need quotes for simple strings like `blue`, but I wasn't sure about numeric values, so I kept them.

Answer (score 6):

First find the condition that occurs in all situations, then filter the special conditions:

```
$('[myc="blue"]')
    .filter('[myid="1"],[myid="3"]');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your special case it would be

```
a=$('[myc="blue"][myid="1"],[myc="blue"][myid="3"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery uses CSS selectors to select elements, so you just need to use more than one rule by separating them with commas, as so:

```
a=$('[myc="blue"], [myid="1"], [myid="3"]');
```

Edit:

Sorry, you wanted blue and 1 or 3. How about:

```
a=$('[myc="blue"][myid="1"],  [myid="3"]');
```

Putting the two attribute selectors together gives you AND, using a comma gives you OR.

Comment: I think, he want's the `myc == blue && (id == 1 || id == 3)`

Comment: You need to repeat the `[myc="blue"]` selector in the second example.

Answer (score -1):

To properly select the elements using the logical operations that you've stated, you just need `jQuery.filter()` for the `AND` operation, not "special filter functions".  You also need `jQuery.add()` for the `OR` operation.

```
var elements = $('[myc="blue"]').filter('[myid="1"').add('[myid="3"');
```

Alternatively, it is possible to accomplish using shorthand in a single selector, where jamming selectors together acts as an `AND` and separating with a comma acts as an `OR`:

```
var elements = $('[myc="blue"][myid="1"], [myid="3"]');
```