# jquery select by attribute using AND and OR operator part 2

Tags: javascript, jquery

i looked the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687131/jquery-select-by-attribute-using-and-and-or-operator)

him need know `$(   [myc="blue"] AND ([myid="1"] OR [myid="3"])   )` 
that last answer is `$('[myc="blue"][myid="1"],[myc="blue"][myid="3"]')`

now i need use for more condition
like -> `$(  ([myc="blue"] OR [myc="red"]) AND ([myid="1"] OR [myid="3"])   )`

please show me the way T.T

Comment: `$( ([myc="blue"] OR [myc="red"]) AND ([myid="1"] OR [myid="3"]) )` : how is it different from having only OR as in `$('[myc="blue"],[myc="red"],[myid="1"],[myid="3"]')`?

Comment: @dystroy It is different. Same as ((true or false) AND (false or false)); this would fail in the original post and yours will not

Comment: do you mean  `blue and 1` or `blue and 2` or `red and 1` or `red and 2`?

Comment: @melc yes , and my project had more condition , can the Code be more smart?

Comment: Please improve your English, it's almost unreadable. (Not a native English speaker my self)

Comment: @user3081959 yeap check answer given by Felix Kling , you can use filter together with combinations to make your solution more elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To not have to write down every possible attribute combination, use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('[myc="blue"], [myc="red"]').filter('[myid="1"], [myid="3"]');
```

This selects all elements with a `myc` attribute with values either "blue" or "red". Then it reduces the set to the elements which also have a `myid` attribute with values "1" or "3".

If you invest a little of your time and [have a look at all the possible selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), you can figure out the solution for such problems on your own.

Comment: my project is work! use like $('ul[data*="checkA1"], [data*="checkA2"]').filter('ul[data*="checkB1"], [data*="checkB3"]').filter('ul[data*="checkC1"], [data*="checkC5"]');

Answer (score 1):

Your expression

```
$( ([myc="blue"] OR [myc="red"]) AND ([myid="1"] OR [myid="3"]) )
```

can be developed as

```
$( [myc="blue"] AND [myid="1"] 
  OR [myc="blue"] AND [myid="3"]
  OR [myc="red"] AND [myid="1"] 
  OR [myc="red"] AND [myid="3"] )
```

Try this code:

```
$('[myc="blue"][myid="1"],[myc="blue"][myid="3"],[myc="red"][myid="1"],[myc="red"][myid="3"]')
```

Comment: i don't think this can happen `[myc="blue"][myc="red"]` .

Comment: Sorry I made a typo, see my corrected answer