# jQuery cross section of filters

Tags: jquery, object, filter

For a website I'm building I'm using filters to select all items between an price range and or build date and or make etc.. So basically I'm combining a lot of filters on a need as basis.

I've tested each filter alone and they work.

How can I get a cross section of those filters?

So:

- Filter 1 matches [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
- Filter 2 matches [2,4,6,8]
- Filter 3 matches [3,4,5]

I'd like to find a way to get the cross section of those matches so I end up with [4].

In order to keep it understandable in the future I do not want create one big filter.

Any thoughts or help?

Comment: Can you please add your JS and HTML code to the question.

Comment: Take a look in this link. It seems to me that this answers your question.


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687131/jquery-select-by-attribute-using-and-and-or-operators