# select matching elements whose sibling element has a specific class

Tags: jquery

I want to select all links that a direct child of a table cell, so I have the following selector:

```
$('td a')
```

But I want to add another filter to this. I only want to select those table cell links that have a direct sibling with a class of 'moda'. In other words, the following will match:

```
<td>
  <a data-target="#unresolvedTasks" data-toggle="modal" href="#" style="">dfsgdfg fghfghjhgj</a>
  <div class="modal fade" id="unresolvedTasks" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
</td>
```

I did a google search about AND conditions, which gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687131/jquery-select-by-attribute-using-and-and-or-operators) link. But this is a different type of AND condition:

```
a=$('[myc="blue"][myid="1"][myid="3"]');
```

That will select an element that meets all those criteria. I want to select an element that meets a specific criteria and then also check if its sibling meets a specific criteria.

I tried this:

```
$('td a, td a + div[class="modal"]')
```

But that is doing an OR condition not an AND condition.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use

```
$('td > div.modal').prev('a')
```

and if you want to loop through them

```
$('td').each(function(){
    console.log($(this).find('div.modal').prev('a').attr('data-target'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td div.modal').siblings('a')
```

Demo
http://jsfiddle.net/phv12hbu/