# How to select element has attribute and attribute not equal to specific value using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attributes, selector

I got the following line:

```
$("element").find("[attr!='val'][attr!='val'][attr!='val'][attr!='val'][attr!='val']")
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687131/jquery-select-by-attribute-using-and-and-or-operators) answer.
My page stops running. My assumption is that it finds all the different elements in the page, also the ones that don't have the attribute. Is that correct?
If so how can I fix this?
I tried the

```
$("element").not("[attr='val']") 
// instead of 
$("element").find("[attr!='val']")
```

and it still crashed the page.
The following code works of course:

```
$("element").find("[attr='val']")
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle? why you don't use just one .find()

Comment: You can try to use `:not([attr='val'])`

Comment: @jcubic i.e `jQuery('#element'):not([attr='val'])` as opposed to .not?

Comment: What is your parent selector? Is it the entire document?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob No, Forgot that. that means my assumption is incorrect. thanks

Comment: @IsaacDj, I was directing to the OP

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob I am the OP

Comment: Sorry, doing too much at one time

Comment: @Mohammad I want it to have the attribute and it to be equal to a value which is not one of the specifics I wrote down

Comment: Add `[attr]` to your selector. `.find("[attr][attr!='val']...") `

Comment: @Mohammad perfect, thank you. What did the code actually do which failed beforehand?

Comment: @IsaacDj It was returning all the elements that don't have the attribute at all, since a non-existent attribute is not equal to the value.

Comment: @IsaacDj It would also help if you selected a specific tag, e.g. `span[attr!='val']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery [Has Attribute Selector `[name]`](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) select element only has attribute without consider to it value. You need to adding `[attr]` at the first of your selector.

```js
$("ul").find("[class][class!='A']").css("color", "red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="A">A</li>
  <li class="A">A</li>
  <li class="B">B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```