# Javascript OR operator in variable assignment with jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery

Given this simple `ul`:

```
<ul class="dummy">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

And this jQuery code:

```
var container = $('.dummy');
var active = container.children('li.active') || container.children('li:first-child')
console.log(active.html());
```

According to what I know about using `||` in variable assignment, I'd expect that the first `li` should be selected, since there are no `li.active` (see also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100758/javascript-or-variable-assignment-explanation))

Instead, in the `console.log` I get `undefined` instead of `One`: seems that the `container.children('li:first-child')` is never evaluated

Where am I wrong? Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfatv1ft/1/)... Thanks a lot!

Comment: see this for AND, OR operations:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687131/jquery-select-by-attribute-using-and-and-or-operators

Comment: try writing the inline like this: `(container.children('li.active') || container.closest('li') ? true : false)`

Comment: `container.children('li.active')` will never be null/undefined as it will always be a JQuery object, whether or not it has any elements is a different matter.

Comment: phuzi is right, consider using [.length](https://api.jquery.com/length/). See updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfatv1ft/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jQuery method returns a jQuery object which will always be **truthy**; thus you are getting `undefined`. if you are only intending to get HTML you can use.

```
var active = container.children('li.active').html() || container.children('li:first-child').html();
```

However you want to get the element, do away with `||` and use `.length` property to check if element exists.

```
var active = container.children('li.active');
if(active.length == 0)
    active = container.children('li:first-child')
```

```js
var container = $('.dummy');
var active = container.children('li.active').html() || container.children('li:first-child').html()
console.log(active);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="dummy">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following values are considered as "false" in JavaScript.

- false
- null
- "" (empty string)
- 0
- Nan
- undefined

The `||` operator will work for those cases. In your case `container.children('li.active')` is not returning anyone of above value, It is jquery selector object. So in this case the second option will not execute.

Please console this statement you will get some clarification. `console.log(container.children('li.active'))`