# How to hide div when one of the child elements (img) has a specific property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my webpage I have a label and a checkbox.
The checkbox is generated by Salesforce (*hence the span id looks dynamic*).

This is the code snippet from my webpage.

```
<div class="fds" id="checkinput">
<label>Additional Review</label>
<span id="j_id0:asp-acc-details:as-c1">
<img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" title="Not Checked">
</span>
</div>
```

The `span` tag and the underlying `img` is generated by Salesforce.

I would like to know if possible via jQuery to render the "`checkinput`" div invisible or hidden if the img tag's title (or alt) is "Not Checked".

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `attr()` method to check the value of your image attributes:

```js
(function() {
  var img = $(".checkImg");
  if (img.attr("title") === "Not Checked" || img.attr("alt") === "Not Checked")
    $("#checkinput").hide();
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fds" id="checkinput">
  <label>Additional Review</label>
  <span id="j_id0:asp-acc-details:as-c1">
     <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" title="Not Checked"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Edit** If you have several of those `div`s with their images and you want to process them all in the same way, try this:

```js
(function() {
  $(".fds img").each(function() {
    var img = $(this);
    if (img.attr("title") === "Not Checked" || img.attr("alt") === "Not Checked")
      img.closest(".fds").hide();
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fds" id="checkinput1">
  <label>Review</label>
  <span id="j_id0:asp-acc-details:as-c1">
     <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" title="Checked"/>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="fds" id="checkinput2">
  <label>Additional Review</label>
  <span id="j_id0:asp-acc-details:as-c2">
     <img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" title="Not Checked"/>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes of course. Simply change `$("#checkinput")` to `$(".fds")`. But if there are other elements with the same class, they will all hide.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can make the jquery to run the above code only for elements which are present inside the div of class "fds" ?. The reason I ask I do not want this code snippet to run on other checkboxes which are present in the web page and which are generated by the Salesforce. Thanks  in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

Use `find` & `attr` method to get the img and its title attribute.Then use `hide` method to hide the `div`

```js
var titleConstant = "Not Checked";

var getImgTitle = $("#checkinput").find("img").attr('title');
if (getImgTitle === titleConstant) {
  $("#checkinput").hide()

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fds" id="checkinput">
  <label>Additional Review</label>
  <span id="j_id0:asp-acc-details:as-c1">
<img src="/img/checkbox_checked.gif" alt="Not Checked" width="21" height="16" class="checkImg" title="Not Checked">
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `$("[],[]")` [OR syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687131/jquery-select-by-attribute-using-and-and-or-operators) to select based on those attributes.

```js
    $( "[img[alt='Not Checked']], [img[title='Not Checked']]" ).each(function(img) {
      
      $(img).parent().parent().hide() // using parent relationship to hide

      // $(img).closest(".fds").hide() // alternative using class to hide
      // $("#checkinput").hide(); // alternative using id to hide
    })
```